# What's a good name for this kind of object?

Tags: python, data-structures, terminology, naming

I have an associative array of element IDs to counts of each element.
e.g. (in python):

```
myObject = { 'a': 5, 'b': 3 }
```

It should support addition and subtraction. For example:

```
myObject - { 'a': 3 }
```

Should evaluate to:

```
{ 'a': 2, 'b': 3 }
```

For context, this is supporting a costs system. Each element is a resource type, and the quantity is how much of that resource the entity owns. A user would have one of these objects as an inventory of some kind, but then an item might have one of these as its cost. As a result, the user object can simply subtract the item's cost from their inventory.

I'm just trying to think of a good term for this kind of object.

Comment: That's not an associative array, it's a dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This collection type is already in Python 2.7 and 3.1. It's called a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: And the substraction example is nearly identical to the one in the question (except 5 != 4) - win! +1

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for `ResourceVector` or `ResourceTuple` I guess.

Comment: Neither a vector nor a tuple is a mapping. Both are sequences.

Comment: Why mapping? A vector has components `a,b,c`. You can perform addition component-wise. In fact, a vector is nothing but a mapping to a numeric type. Typically, it's injective in the components (i.e. each component has an associated value) which is not the case here - it implies that non-used components are simply 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would call that a Matrix, without knowing the extent of what you want to do.